# Linearly indipendence of special vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Lets say we have vectors

$\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{array}\right)$,
$\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{0} \\
\vdots \\
x_{m}
\end{array}\right)$,
$\cdots$,
$ \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x_{0}^{n} \\
\vdots \\
x_{m}^{n}
\end{array}\right)$

where $x_i \neq x_j, i \neq j$ and $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Under which conditions are these vectors linearly independent and why?

I thought about looking at the llinear combination of these vecotrs but don't think that this yields an effort.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Thank you, that article helped me.